# unable to print post response

Tags: json, node.js, request, http-post

I'm writing a program in node js that does the following.

1. Get the Access token(a jwt)
2. Get the user firstName from that token
3. Pass this token and firstName to another method to post.
4. print the result.

My program is as below.

```
function getUserDetailsFromAccessToken(session) {

    var token = session.user.accessToken;
    try {
        // parse this and get user attributes
        var decoded = jwt.decode(token);
        getTheUserProfile(decoded.firstname, token, session);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}

var hostUrl= "myUrlToGetResult";

function getTheUserProfile(nameFromSession, token, session) {
    console.log("Incomung values " + nameFromSession);
    console.log("Inside getUsersProfile Block");
    var jsonToPass = {
        "accesstoken": token,
        "domain": "DomainName",
        "lanid": nameFromSession
    };
    console.log("json to pass " + JSON.stringify(jsonToPass));

    var options = {
        uri: hostUrl+ "/api/admin/GetUserInfo",
        method: "POST",
        json: jsonToPass
    };
    request(options, function (error, resp, body) {
    console.log("resp code is " + resp.statusCode);
        if (!error && resp.statusCode == 200) {
            if (body) {
                console.log("Insode B1");
                console.log(body.firstName);
            } else {
                console.log("I am unable to authenticate you. please disable the skill and re link your account");
            }
        } else {
            console.log(error);
        }

    });
}
```

when I run this program, I'm able to print only till `console.log("json to pass " + JSON.stringify(jsonToPass));`, after that I'm unable to get any result from `request()` block.

please let me know where am I going wrong and how can I fix it.

Comment: Is the request callback ever called? From your logic, it's possible the request is returning no error and a status code other than 200. This scenario would lead to the `else` statement being called within the request callback, but nothing be logged.

Comment: Also, when you call `getTheUserProfile` you're passing in 3 arguments, but `getTheUserProfile` only accepts 2.

Comment: @dan, I tried to print value inside the `request()` block, updated the code to `request(options, function (error, resp, body) {
        console.log("resp code is " + resp.statusCode);`, but this is not printing anything, I mean, it is not entering the `request()` block itself. and also I updated the method to have 3 params

Comment: Ok. If you make the same request using Postman or Curl then do you get a response? Could it be an issue with the server you're requesting rather than your logic?

Comment: This thing perfectly works in postman, is there any issue with regards to my call back?

Comment: Not that I can see :( Is options.uri correctly formatted with the protocol etc. I.e. is it a valid definitely a valid URI?

Comment: Yes, everything is correct :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145646/discussion-between-user3872094-and-dan).